# How to delete a worksheet in an existing xls file using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xls

I want to delete a worksheet from an existing **xls file** which I am modifying module `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`. I couldn't find anything on CPAN website. I found a code which deletes worksheets from the end but I want to delete a sheet based on its name. I am attaching the code. Please explain the splice command in that code too. Thanks
Here is the link which I found:

https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=722716

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl -w
> use strict;
> use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
> use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
> my ($INFILE,$OUTFILE)=("in.xls","out.xls");
> my $oExcel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
> my $oBook = $oExcel->Parse($INFILE);
>
> splice(@{$oBook->{Worksheet}},1,1);
> $oBook->{SheetCount}--;
>
> $oExcel->SaveAs($oBook, $OUTFILE);
> ```

Comment: I think the Perlmonks post is useful. You'd have to reach into the object and fiddle with the internals, but you should be able to identify the correct worksheet based on its name, and then remove it.

Comment: Yes. I actually understood the perlmonks code now and I tried it out and it is working. Thanks for the comment simbabque

Comment: I was going to try it and write an answer, but my Libre Office closes when I try to save a file... you can write up your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Perlmonks link in the question](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=722716) helps. If you want to delete a specific sheet use the line

```
splice(@{$oBook->{Worksheet}},1,1);
```

where the initial one represents from which sheet you would like to delete and the next one represents how many sheets you want to delete from the offset.

This is same as normal `splice` command.

After doing this, use the command `$oBook->{SheetCount}--;` to delete worksheets.